# esp8266 cant make more than one request at time

Tags: esp8266, http

i am trying to make a get request, read that request and make another request with that read value. i havent shown it in this code but i want to make a request inside in a request. is it possible to make a request without ending one, if its, how do i do that?

here is the code :

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h>

#define WIFI_SSID "ssid"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "pw"

void conn();
void getreq();
void anothergetreq();

void setup() {
  conn();
  getreq();
}

void loop() {
}

void getreq() {
  std::unique_ptr<BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure>client(new BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure);
  client->setInsecure();
  HTTPClient http;

  http.begin(*client, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1");

  int httpCode = http.GET();
  String payaload = http.getString();
  Serial.print("HTTP CODE: "); Serial.println(httpCode);
  Serial.print("PAYLOAD: "); Serial.println(payaload);
  //here i presume got the value from payload, and making another request with it
  anothergetreq("posts/1");
  http.end();


}
void anothergetreq(String p) {

  std::unique_ptr<BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure>client(new BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure);
  client->setInsecure();
  HTTPClient http;

  http.begin(*client, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"+p);

  int httpCode = http.GET();
  String payaload = http.getString();

  Serial.print("HTTP CODE: "); Serial.println(httpCode);
  Serial.print("PAYLOAD: "); Serial.println(payaload);
  http.end();
}


void conn() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
}
```

here is the output:

```
Connected with IP: 192.168.1.100

HTTP CODE: 200
PAYLOAD: {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "username": "Bret",
  "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
  "address": {
    "street": "Kulas Light",
    "suite": "Apt. 556",
    "city": "Gwenborough",
    "zipcode": "92998-3874",
    "geo": {
      "lat": "-37.3159",
      "lng": "81.1496"
    }
  },
  "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
  "website": "hildegard.org",
  "company": {
    "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
    "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
    "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
  }
}
HTTP CODE: -1
PAYLOAD:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/readme.html#bearssl-client-secure-and-server-secure

> Secure clients and servers require siginificant amounts of additional
>   memory and processing to enable their cryptographic algorithms. In
>   general, only a single secure client or server connection at a time
>   can be processed given the little RAM present on the ESP8266

you have two BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure instances at time. it is simple to change your code to first free the first SSL client object.

Comment: i got the compile error "'client' was not declared in this scope" if i only use one ssl client object.

Comment: you can use two. only delete the first (from runtime memory, not from code) before using the second. it is possible that calling http.end() before making the second request will be enough

Comment: i dont know how to free that allocated memory, could you please show me. i managed to fully run and get the response by stopping client using  `client->stop();`. thank you.